# Receiving an object which contains an IFormFile

Tags: .net, angular, http, webapi

I am trying to send a object which contains a `FormData` object from my Angular service to my .Net 6 Web Api end point.

Here is the angular service method:

```
 uploadProfilePicture(file: File) {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', file);

    const image = new AppImage();
    image.fileData = formData;     

    return this.http.post<ImageUploadResult>(`${this.baseUrl}Upload-Profile-Picture`, image);
   
 }
```

This is the `AppImage` typescript class:

```
export class AppImage {
    id: number;
    fileType: string;
    fileData: FormData;
    url: string;
}
```

This is the end point I am trying to reach:

```
  [HttpPost("Upload-Profile-Picture")]
        public async Task<ImageUploadResult> UploadProfilePicture(ImageFileimage image)
        {
            var result = this.fileService.UploadFile(image, User.GetUserId());
            if(result.Error == null)
            {
                var user = await this.userService.FindByIdAsync(User.GetUserId());
                user.ProfilePictureUrl = result.Url.ToString();
                await this.userService.UpdateUser(user);
            }
            return (ImageUploadResult)result;
        }
```

This is the `ImageFile` model class in .NET:

```
 public class ImageFile : IFile
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 

        public string FileType { get; set; } = null!;

        public IFormFile FileData { get; set; } = null!;

        public string Url { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    }
```

The end point is not being hit when calling the `uploadProfilePicture` Angular service method and I just receive the following error in the browsers console:

> Deserialization of interface types is not supported. Type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile'. Path: $.fileData | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 13.

Does anyone know why I am receiving this error?

If I just send up the `FormData` object by itself, the issue does not present itself and the end point is hit.

Answer (score 0):

try using `[FromForm]` as follows:

```
public async Task<ImageUploadResult> UploadProfilePicture([FromForm]ImageFile image)
```

and :

```
uploadProfilePicture(file: File) {

   const formData = new FormData();

   formData.append('fileData', file); 

   //You can add other properties in this way
   //formData.append('id', 1); 
   //formData.append('fileType', "jpg");

   return this.http.post<ImageUploadResult>(`${this.baseUrl}Upload-Profile-Picture`, formData);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your resonse. Wih the above code, I'm no longer getting the error as mentioned in the OP but I'm getting a validation error: "The FileData field is required". Suggesting that the FileData field is empty when it's sent. I'm definitely selecting a valid file as it's the same one I used when testing the end point with just the `FormData` object